# What can a printer know of love? (reading textures in the Stanley Parable)

Tags: the-stanley-parable

In the Stanley Parable, the computers, floors and desks are littered with poignant messeges that add detail and atmosphere. For example, right outside the first room by a copy machine

[image: A poem apparently printed by the printer]

Trouble is, most of these message are impossible to get at the right angle to read at. Additionally, I can't seem to find high enough resolution settings even when I do (picture was from my best screenshot). Is there any way to read all the textures in the game?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, with [VTFEdit](http://nemesis.thewavelength.net/index.php?c=178) you can view the contents of `.vtf` filese. Go to

```
<steamfolder>/steamapps/common/The Stanley Parable/thestanleyparable/materials
```

and double click on a `.vtf` file to view that set of textures.

[image: Screenshot of a VTFEdit window viewing a brick wall texture]

Comment: For the record, the sheet in question can be found at `/models/props_parable/papersheets_5.vtf`