# What does this note say in the Stanley Parable?

Tags: the-stanley-parable

Using the information from a [previous question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/138234/what-can-a-printer-know-of-love-reading-textures-in-the-stanley-parable), I've been mining the textures in the Stanley Parable and came across this:

[image]

which I found in-game in the

> control room with the hundreds of number television screens.

**Is this a secret-coded message? What does it mean?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The characters looked like [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) character maps (note the abundance of 32's which correspond to a space) so I transcribed the message and wrote a small Python script to decode the message:

> “I just played your game and I'd like to say it was the most annoying thing I ever played. It had its cool moments but overall the experience was only of annoyance. The problem is that it does not touch the heart of people. It's a very emotionless game.
>
> Did you ask any girls to try out your game? I ask because they are blissfully less logical than us guys. I am very logical myself, but also very emotional, so it was easy for me to find the game annoying.
>
> What happened is that your game frustrated me. I felt like I was being taken into someone else's hallways, doors and plans, to deliver me an experience that didn't touch me. And worst of all, I'm watching you" - 1112800

This is the text spoken by the Narrator from the [Raphael trailer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WF1L2LSP4eY). I'm not the first to discover this (there are several links in the Steam forums when you know what you are looking for), but I thought I'd share this extra Easter Egg as a self QA.

Comment: It's always a treat to read an unsolicited angry email written by an idiot.

Answer (score 2):

Kudos to Hooked for figuring this out, but I was curious myself and replicated his efforts.  To save others from redoing this, [here](https://github.com/chicks-net/game-configs/blob/master/The_Stanley_Parable/number_message.txt) are the numbers:

`226 128 156 73 32 106 117 115 116 32 112 108 97 121 101
100 32 121 111 117 114 32 103 97 109 101 32 97 110 100
32 73 39 100 32 108 105 107 101 32 116 111 32 115 97
121 32 105 32 119 97 115 32 116 104 101 32 109 111 115
116 32 97 110 110 111 121 105 110 103 32 116 105 110
103 32 73 32 101 118 101 114 32 112 108 97 121 101 100
46 32 116 32 104 97 100 32 105 116 115 32 99 111 111
108 32 109 111 109 101 110 116 32 98 117 116 32 111 118
101 114 97 108 108 32 116 104 101 32 101 120 112 101
114 105 101 110 97 101 32 119 97 115 32 111 110 108 121
32 111 102 32 97 110 110 111 121 97 110 99 101 46 32 84
104 101 32 112 114 111 98 108 101 109 32 115 32 116 104
97 116 32 105 116 32 100 111 101 115 32 110 111 116 32
116 111 117 99 104 32 116 104 101 32 104 101 97 114 116
32 111 102 32 112 101 111 112 108 101 46 32 73 116 39
115 32 97 32 118 101 114 121 32 101 109 111 116 105 111
110 108 101 115 32 103 97 109 101 46 13 10 13 10 68 105
100 32 121 111 117 32 97 115 107 32 97 121 32 103 105
114 108 115 32 116 111 32 116 114 121 32 117 116 32 121
111 117 114 32 103 97 109 101 63 32 73 32 97 115 107 32
98 101 99 97 117 115 101 32 116 104 101 121 32 97 114
101 32 98 108 105 115 115 102 117 108 108 121 32 108
101 115 115 32 108 111 103 105 99 97 108 32 116 104 97
110 32 117 115 32 103 117 121 115 46 32 73 32 97 109 32
118 101 114 121 32 108 111 103 105 99 97 108 32 109 121
115 101 108 102 44 32 98 117 116 32 97 108 115 111 32
118 101 114 121 32 101 109 111 105 111 110 97 108 44 32
115 111 32 105 116 32 119 97 115 32 101 97 115 121 32
102 111 114 32 109 101 32 116 111 32 102 105 110 100 32
116 104 101 32 103 97 109 101 32 110 111 121 105 110
103 46 13 10 13 10 87 104 116 32 104 97 112 112 101 110
101 100 32 105 115 32 116 104 97 116 32 121 111 117 32
97 109 101 32 102 114 117 115 116 114 97 116 101 100 32
109 101 46 32 73 32 102 101 108 116 32 108 105 107 101
32 73 32 119 97 115 32 98 101 105 110 103 32 116 97 107
101 110 32 105 110 116 111 32 115 111 109 101 111 110
101 32 101 108 115 101 39 115 32 104 97 108 108 119 97
121 115 44 32 100 111 111 114 115 32 97 110 100 32 112
108 97 110 115 44 32 116 111 32 100 101 108 105 118 101
114 32 109 101 32 97 110 32 101 120 112 101 114 105 101
110 99 101 32 116 104 97 116 32 100 105 100 110 39 116
32 116 111 117 99 104 32 109 101 46 32 65 110 100 32
119 111 114 115 116 32 111 102 32 97 108 108 44 32 73
39 109 32 119 97 116 99 104 105 110 103 32 121 111 117
32 45 32 49 49 49 50 56 48 48 32 13 10`

Hooked was kind to the original email author and fixed a number of grammatical errors.  This seems to be what was posted:

> “I just played your game and I'd like to say i was the most annoying ting I ever played. t had its cool moment but overall the experienae was only of annoyance. The problem s that it does not touch the heart of people. It's a very emotionles game.
>
> Did you ask ay girls to try ut your game? I ask because they are blissfully less logical than us guys. I am very logical myself, but also very emoional, so it was easy for me to find the game noying.
>
> Wht happened is that you ame frustrated me. I felt like I was being taken into someone else's hallways, doors and plans, to deliver me an experience that didn't touch me. And worst of all, I'm watching you - 1112800

I have double checked most of those errors and I fixed all of the translation errors I found.  Feel free to bug me here or on [github](https://github.com/chicks-net/game-configs/tree/master/The_Stanley_Parable) if you find any more problems.  My version of the python decoder is also on [github](https://github.com/chicks-net/game-configs/tree/master/The_Stanley_Parable).